# How to kill a thread without using Thread.stop() method in Java

Tags: java, android, adb

I collect adb logs in my application while my java automation framework runs tests. I want to kill the thread that I use to collect adb logcat logs. I want to do that instantly. Right now I find the PID of the logcat instance and then I shut it down.
Sadly my suite runs over another triggering mechanism which also creates an instance of logcat and my java code kills the wring process.
Is there a way to kill the thread instantly or is there a way to kill the process that I created with Runtime. get run time().exec.??

Comment: If the thread supports _cooperative_ shutdown, `Thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: What about Process.destroy()?

Comment: Process.destroy() worked. thanks.